# Tools to track internal traffic

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Google Analytics is a great analytics tool. However I find it's not easy when it comes to tracking INTERNAL traffic.

For example, let's say I put a banner on my ecommerce advertising a specific product, and want to see how many people buy it thanks to this? Or maybe I add a "best seller" box somewhere and want to see what sales it brings me.

Can I do that cleanly and easily with Google Analytics?

Or are there better tools out there suited for tracking internal traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Google Analytics You can implement event tracking, that's what you need, with events you can track clicks on internal sections (banners, flash, file downloads) and you wont mess with campaigns.
Check it out [Google Analytics Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerOverview.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Campaigns to achieve this, even though they can also be used with external traffic. Start here: https://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/topic.py?topic=1007028.

> Google Analytics accurately tracks visitors from a variety of sources,
>   such as search engines or email links, to conversions or **transactions
>   on your site**, and provides closed-loop ROI analysis. [my emphasis]

Comment: -1. This is bad, as going forward, it will trigger a new visit.

Comment: It triggers new visits or erase previous data such as the original source and campaign